# MySQL query with multiple joins taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. The first one is called `map_life`, the second one is called `scripts` and the third one is called `npc_data`.

I'm running the following query to get all the properties from `map_life` while also getting the `script` column from `scripts` and the `storage_cost` column from `npc_data` if the ids match.

```
SELECT life.*
     , script.script
     , npc.storage_cost 
  FROM map_life life 
  LEFT 
  JOIN scripts script 
    ON script.objectid = life.lifeid 
   AND script.script_type = 'npc' 
  LEFT 
  JOIN npc_data npc 
    ON npc.npcid = life.lifeid
```

As you can see, `map_life` id is `lifeid`, while `scripts` id is `objectid` and `npc_data` id is `npcid`.

This query is taking about 5 seconds to execute, and I have no idea why. Here's the CREATE statements for all those 3 tables, maybe I'm missing something?

```
CREATE TABLE  `mcdb83`.`map_life` (
  `id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mapid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `life_type` enum('npc','mob','reactor') NOT NULL,
  `lifeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `life_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'For reactors, specifies a handle so scripts may interact with them; for NPC/mob, this field is useless',
  `x_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `foothold` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `min_click_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_click_pos` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `respawn_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` set('faces_left') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lifetype` (`mapid`,`life_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32122 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE  `mcdb83`.`scripts` (
  `script_type` enum('npc','reactor','quest','item','map_enter','map_first_enter') NOT NULL,
  `helper` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'Represents the quest state for quests, and the index of the script for NPCs (NPCs may have multiple scripts).',
  `objectid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `script` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`script_type`,`helper`,`objectid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Lists all the scripts that belong to NPCs/reactors/etc. ';

CREATE TABLE  `mcdb83`.`npc_data` (
  `npcid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `storage_cost` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` set('maple_tv','is_guild_rank') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`npcid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Good. Next provide the EXPLAIN for the above.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT l.*, s.script, npc.storage_cost 
FROM map_life l LEFT JOIN
     scripts s 
     ON s.objectid = l.lifeid AND
        s.script_type = 'npc' LEFT JOIN
     npc_data npc 
     ON npc.npcid = l.lifeid;
```

You want indexes on: `scripts(object_id, script_type, script)` and `npc_data(npcid, storage_cost)`.  The order of the columns in these indexes is important.

Answer (score 0):

1. `map_life.lifeid` does not have any indexes defined, therefore the joins will result in full table scans. Define an index on `map_life.lifeid` field.
2. In scripts table the primary key is defined on the following fields in that order: `script_type`, `helper`, `objectid`. The join is done on `objectid` and there is a constant filter criterion on `script_type`. Because the order of the fields in the index is wrong, MySQL cannot use the primary key for this query. For this query the order of the fields in the index should b: `objectid`, `script_type`, `helper`.

The above will significantly speed up the joins. You may further increase the speed of the query if your indexes actually cover all fields that are in the query because in this case MySQL does not even have to touch the tables.

Consider adding an index with the following fields and order to the `scripts` table: `object_id, script_type, script` and `npcid, storage_cost` index to `npc_data` table. However, these indexes may slow down insert / update / delete statements, so do some performance testing before adding these indexes to production environment.